# Possible Oracle-Bug with SubQueries and Group Functions

Tags: sql, oracle

can anybody explain me why the following Query returns two Rows and not only one?

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 'ASDF' c1, MAX (SUM (1)) c2
          FROM DUAL
         GROUP BY dummy
        UNION
        SELECT 'JKLÖ' c1, 1 c2
          FROM DUAL)
 WHERE c1 != 'ASDF';

--another Version with the same wrong result:
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 c1, MAX (SUM (1)) c2
          FROM DUAL
         GROUP BY dummy
        UNION all
        SELECT 2 c1, 1 c2
          FROM DUAL)
 WHERE c1 != 1;
```

Is it correct that Oracle delivers two rows? In my opinion the Row with c1 = ASDF should not be in the result.

Here is a Screenshot of the result from the first query:

[image]

I have tested it on the following Versions, always with the same result:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
- Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Can you include the result set?

Comment: Doesn't `group by dummy` cause a syntax error?

Comment: Screenshot of the result set is included. No, no syntax error - i have the problem also with real tables, i only made the sample as easy and small as possible.

Comment: Guessing the accented character is promoting the type to some kind of wide char that subsequently fails the test against ASCII

Comment: No, it also does not work if i use Numbers: SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 c1, MAX (SUM (1)) c2
          FROM DUAL
         GROUP BY dummy
        UNION
        SELECT 2 c1, 1 c2
          FROM DUAL)
 WHERE c1 != 1;

Comment: @GordonLinoff: no, the `dual` table contains a single column named `dummy`

Comment: Bug. Also notice how c2 is **NULL** and not **1**

Comment: @bernhard.weingartner - it may help if you edit your post and change the strings to 'a' and 'b' (and update the output) - and perhaps also change UNION to UNION ALL - to prevent more guesses like those above.

Comment: This seems to be caused by the nesting of aggregates - something other DBMS reject anyway. If you replace `MAX(SUM(1))` with `SUM(1)` the it works correctly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I don't understand that point. Why would any DBMS reject that? The SUM(...) is for each group (the query has a GROUP BY clause). Then in the SELECT, you can aggregate any row-level expressions (even if "row" is now one row per group, and the expression is a group-level aggregate). The MAX is at the full table level. So why should this not be a valid expression?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - for example I think this is perfectly fine, to find the maximum total salary by department: `select max(sum(sal)) from scott.emp group by deptno` - what is wrong with that? And, in any case, that runs perfectly fine and returns the correct result, so that alone does not explain the bug Berhnard has encountered.

Comment: @mathguy: probably nothing "wrong", but many other DBMS do not allow nesting of aggregates like that (at least SQL Server, Postgres and even MySQL).

Comment: [The docs explicitly say you can nest aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm). Since this seems to be a bug with predicate pushing and nested aggregates you should raise a service request with Oracle. (I can't see anything obvious on MoS, and as it gets the same result on at least 10g-12c it may be a new scenario).

Comment: I blame `DUAL` and its special nature. Reproduce this without it.

Comment: lol @Phil - why don't you do the work. Create a table and a query and report back that you haven't seen the bug happen in that setup.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No this is not a bug</strike>. Aggregate functions are the reason why you see this unexpected result. Here is how it works. `SUM()` function as well as `MAX()` function will return NULL(producing 1 row) if there is no rows returned by the query. When your query is executed optimizer applies `predicate pushing` transformation and your original query becomes(will not post the entire trace, only transformed query):

```
SELECT "from$_subquery$_001"."C1" "C1",
       "from$_subquery$_001"."C2"  "C2" 
   FROM  ( 
           (SELECT 'ASDF' "C1",MAX(SUM(1)) "C2" 
              FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" 
             WHERE 'ASDF'<>'ASDF'       [1]-- predicate pushed into the view 
             GROUP BY "DUAL"."DUMMY" )
             UNION 
            (SELECT 'JKLÖ' "C1",
                  1 "C2" 
              FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL" 
             WHERE 'JKLÖ'<>'ASDF')) "from$_subquery$_001"
```

[1] Because of predicate pushing your fist sub-query returns no rows and when an aggregate function(except `count` and few others), `MAX` or `SUM` or even both as in this case  used on empty result set `NULL` will be returned - 1 row + 1 row return by the second sub-query thus producing 2 rows result set you are looking at.

Here is simple demonstration:

```
create table empty_table (c1 varchar2(1));

select 'aa' literal, nvl(max(c1), 'NULL') as res
  from empty_table

LITERAL RES 
------- ----
aa      NULL

1 row selected.
```

Comment: You just explained that this **IS** a bug. Predicate pushing should not be done with a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` if it changes the result. The query has the predicate in the outer query. Pushing it and producing a different result is something wrong that the Optimizer is doing, so that is a bug. The query itself neither requested not expected the predicate to be pushed.

Comment: @mathguy  Well here is why I said that this is not a bug. We have inline view with `UNION` set operator, which prevents  view merging (`UNION[ALL] prevents view merging not predicate pushing`) and optimizer has no other choice but push that predicate(filter push down transformation takes place). We can prevent predicate pushing in this case by "materializing" (using `materialize` hint) that view .  After looking a bit deeper into this... yeah, wrong result produced forcing us to look for a work around. Agree, looks like bug.

Comment: We are agreeing... in what you said, the "optimizer has no choice but to push the predicate" is the part we would disagree on, since the optimizer always has the choice to leave predicates alone where they are. That is in Oracle's control, pushing predicates is not required either by logic or the standards. But as I said, it is now clear that we are in agreement. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It definitely looks like a bug.

I don't really know how to read explain plans, but here it is. It seems to me the predicate has been pushed to only one of the UNION members and it has been transformed into "NULL IS NOT NULL" which is totally weird.

Note that the strings could be changed to 'a' and 'b' (so we don't use special characters), UNION and UNION ALL produce the same bug, and the bug seems to be triggered by the MAX(SUM(1)) in the first branch; simply replacing that with NULL or anything else that's "simple", or even with SUM(1) (without the MAX) causes the query to work correctly.

**ADDED**: Strangely, if I change `MAX(SUM(1))` to either `MAX(1)` or `SUM(1)`, or if I simply change it to the literal number `1`, the query works correctly - but the Explain Plan still shows the same weird predicate, "NULL IS NOT NULL". So, it seems the problem is that the predicate is not pushed to both branches of the union, not the predicate transformation. (And even that doesn't explain why `c2` appears as `NULL` in the extra row in the result set.) **MORE ADDED** (see Comments below) - as it turns out, the predicate IS pushed to both branches of the UNION, and this is exactly what causes the problem (as Nicholas explains in his answer).

```
Plan hash value: 1682090214

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |      |     2 |    32 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  VIEW                  |      |     2 |    32 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    SORT AGGREGATE      |      |     1 |     2 |            |          |
|   4 |     HASH GROUP BY      |      |     1 |     2 |            |          |
|*  5 |      FILTER            |      |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |    FAST DUAL           |      |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter(NULL IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: With just max *or* sum, pushing the predicate into the first branch gets no rows; with `max(sum())` it gets a single row with null (you can run that standalone to check), which in itself is right (and is what Nicholas is showing). But as you say pushing the predicate into the subquery looks wrong in this situation. I guess the optimiser isn't taking the nested aggregates into account when it decides to do that, or something...

Comment: @AlexPoole - I understand that from Nicholas's answer, and he makes a perfectly fine point (I didn't think of it); the only disagreement I have with him is that he states this is not a bug. (I think he will agree with my comment after he reads it though.)

Comment: Yeah, just explaining the 'strangely' part - to myself when I started - which does make sense; the odd-looking filter makes sense in that context too, in both cases.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Oh, I re-read what I wrote, in light of what Nicholas explained. My speculation is wrong - the predicate IS pushed to both branches, which is exactly what causes the issue! I'll add a note about this in my answer.

Comment: @mathguy @AlexPoole another quirk is the way you get different results when you run `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 c1, MAX (SUM (1)) c2 FROM DUAL WHERE NULL IS NOT NULL GROUP BY dummy);` vs
`SELECT 1 c1, MAX (SUM (1)) c2 FROM DUAL WHERE NULL IS NOT NULL GROUP BY dummy;`. The filter step is done last in the former and earlier in the latter (at least, in 11.2.0.4). WTF, optimizer?! *{;-)

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler example results in the same error:

```
 SELECT 'ASDF' c1, MAX (SUM (1)) c2
    FROM DUAL where 'ASDF' <> 'ASDF'
GROUP BY dummy
```

I must confess that I am totally confused. Why doesn't the filter eliminate the record, thereby eliminating any result set?

[image: Explain Plan from TOAD]

Comment: Nicholas Krasnov has already explained why it's correct to get a single row with a null value back from that standalone query. The issue is that the filter should be applied later in the OP's scneario, where the aggregation is in a subquery.